# Music through bluetooth speaker but other sounds come through computer

Tags: windows-10, audio, music

I have a `bluetooth speaker` connected to my `Windows 10` laptop.  I play music using `Groove Music` which comes out of the bluetooth speaker.  Other sounds such as zoom chat, or facebook notifications will come through the speaker audio.

I have not changed any settings.  Is it possible to decide what apps output to what speaker?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Zoom can [change the audio output in it's settings](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362623-Changing-settings-in-the-desktop-client-or-mobile-app):

> To access settings in the Zoom client:
>
> 1. Sign in to Zoom.
> 2. Click your profile picture then click Settings.
>    [image]
>    This will open the settings window, giving you access to the following options:
>    [image]
>
> ...
>
> #### Audio
>
> Set your microphone and speaker, test them, adjust their volume, and change other settings.
>
> - **Speaker**: Click Test Speaker to play a test tone. *Click the drop-down menu to select the speaker you want Zoom to use.*
> - **Microphone**: Click Test Mic to record audio and play it back. *Click the drop-down to select the mic you want Zoom to use.*

Look in the Facebook Messenger app for similar settings.

---

Alternatively for programs that simply use the "system default" sound output you can change the output by clicking the sound icon, clicking the name of the speaker device:

[image]

And then selecting the device you want sound to come out of:

[image]